# Angular material slider not sliding

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using `mat-slider` and, while trying to slide the control using the mouse, it does not slide, either on the left or right. It is only working when I click to a point in the sliding line. 
My code is:

```
<div>
    <mat-slider></mat-slider>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you imported MatSliderModule from '@angular/material/slider';?

Comment: Yes I have imported it

Comment: add some width to mat-slider, mat-slider {
  width: 300px;
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4278). Basically I imported `MaterialModule` after `BrowserAnimationsModule`

Answer (score 15):

For those who are using lazy loading, first import this:

```
import { BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { GestureConfig } from '@angular/material';
```

And then, put this in the root app module:

```
  providers: [
    {provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: GestureConfig}
  ]
```

Check [this issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4595#issuecomment-416641018) for more info

Comment: This saved the day! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I know i am late but if anyone stumble upon this issue with the latest version of material(8.2.1), you need to install hammerjs and import it in your main.ts file using below commands

**Install**

```
npm install hammerjs
```

**import on main.ts file**

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

Answer (score 3):

On Angular 9, installing Hammer JS worked for me as others have stated.

1. `npm install hammerjs`
2. Add it to app.module - `imports: [..., HammerModule]`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should install [HammerJS](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/) to your project:

```
npm install hammerjs
```

Hammer is a open-source library that can recognize gestures made by touch, mouse and pointerEvents.

Look at the [Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-5-gesture-support) on HammerJS.

> Some components (mat-slide-toggle, mat-slider, matTooltip) rely on HammerJS for gestures. In order to get the full feature-set of these components, HammerJS must be loaded into the application.

DEMO without HammerJS:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could already have `Hammerjs` installed and imported in the app module, and maybe it didn't work for you.

Verify in the **polyfills.ts** file you have imported hammersjs and `@angular/animations`. This file is found in **src/polyfills.ts**. Open it, If you can't find the following code, paste it into the **polyfills.ts** file.

Note: It should not be commented, eye.

```
import 'hammerjs';
import '@angular/animations';
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material 14:

- you don't need HammerJS
- you don't need to include MatSliderModule in the main module if you are using lazy-loading
- you don't need any GestureConfigs
- if you are using zone.js flags, be sure that "mousemove" is not in __zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS

Comment: thx, really useful to understand issue source ! 
but instead of removing `mousemove` for whole app, solution was to trigger `changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` on `<mat-slider (input)="setMyValueAndTriggerCdRef($event.value)">`